# Insert multiple child records in Access Web App

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

Would anyone be able to help me with inserting multiple records in a junction table when a new record is added? It needs to be done with Macros since this is an Access Web App on SharePoint. I tried to AddNewRecord within a ForEach Loop but it won't work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is important to post the macro that you tried, if you get an error, it is good to post that too.

Comment: Well, the error message, at least, says: Compilation failed because macro AXL is not valid. All I'm doing is editing a record, setting the field, and inserting a new record within a loop.

Comment: Can you first confirm which type of app? Is this a Access 2010 web database or an Access 2013 web app? It's important to know this first because there are many differences between the two.

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry about that. It is an Access 2013 web app used in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Ok, good. Can you post a screenshot of the macro window so we can see what you have tried?